# If statement with negative condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to prepare my data for a histogram. My data (in the following code described with `D`) contains values between `[-200,1000]` and with an `if statement` I want to allocate them to bins of the range `[0,20]`.
My code looks like this:

```
for t in range(0,731):
     if(D[t]<(-130)):
        xbin[t]=0
     if(D[t]>=(-130) and D[t]<=(-120)):
        xbin[t]=1
     if(D[t]>=(-120) and D[t]<=(-110)):
        xbin[t]=2
     if(D[t]>=(-110) and D[t]<=(-100)):
        xbin[t]=3
     if(D[t]>=(-100) and D[t]<=(-50)):
        xbin[t]=4
     if(D[t]>=(-50) and D[t]<=0):
        xbin[t]=5
     if(D[t]>=0 and D[t]<=50):
        xbin[t]=6
```

and so on. But it seems as the program does not understand the negative condition in the if statement. So it allocate all values `<0` to `xbin=6` doesn't matter if the value is `< -120`, `< -130` or something else. 
How can I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to use `elif` for the conditions (except the first)?

Comment: Python also has chained comparison, so you can have your comparison statements structured like e.g. `(-130 <= D[t] < -120)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python understands the negative comparison. The problem is with your conditions that some of then conflict to each other. For refusing that problem you need to use `elif` rather than multiple `if` which makes it check all the conditions. Also you don't need to explicitly write and between your conditions, python will chain the them automatically and they have same precedence.

```
for t in range(0,731):
     if D[t] < -130 :
        xbin[t]=0
     elif -110 <= D[t]<= -120:
        xbin[t]=1
     elif -120 <= D[t] <= -110:
        xbin[t]=2
     elif -110 <= D[t] <= -100:
        xbin[t]=3
     elif -100 <= D[t] <= -50:
        xbin[t]=4
     elif -50 <= D[t] <= 0:
        xbin[t]=5
     elif 0 <= D[t]<= 50:
        xbin[t]=6
```